# react-native-google-places-autocomplete results are white

Tags: react-native

Unable to see the list items in the result list. Spent a full day figuring out what it might be, still unable to resolve it.
When search results appear, I cannot see the text. listview style doesn't color the text.

```
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          returnKeyType={'default'}
          fetchDetails={true}
          minLength={2}
          placeholder="Search"
          textInputProps={{
            placeholderTextColor: '#32a852',
            returnKeyType: 'search',
          }}
          onPress={(data, details = null) => {
            // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
            console.log(data, details);
          }}
          query={{
            key: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            language: 'en',
          }}
          styles={{
            textInput: {
              height: 38,
              color: '#5d5d5d',
              fontSize: 16,
            },
            predefinedPlacesDescription: {
              color: '#1faadb',
            },
            listView: {color: 'black', zIndex: 100000}, // doesnt work, text is still white?
          }}
        />
      </View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In styles, add description for changing the color or any other style attribute.

```
styles = {{
...
description : {color : 'black'}
}}
```

Comment: Thanks. This also worked. 
The issue was due to dark mode.